# How to apply the following rule to my dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

My dataframe =

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': 'a a b b b c c c'.split(),
                   'code': ['103','104','103','103','104','104','104','103'],
                   'qty': [4,4,5,6,11,8,9,0]})
```

I want for each class if there is a code 103 and 104 and if the qty associated to the code 103 > to the qty of the code 104.

I have developed a function for the first part of the problem that doesn't work, but I don't know how to do the second

```
def regle_2(df):
    if (df['code'].any() == '103') & (df['code'].any() == '104'):
        df['bool'] = True
    else:
        df['bool'] = False
    return df
```

and I use it like this

```
g = df.groupby('class').apply(regle_2)
```

and this is the result

```
A       code    qty  bool
0   a   103      4   False
1   a   104      4   False
2   b   103      5   False
3   b   103      6   False
4   b   104      11  False
5   c   104      8   False
6   c   104      9   False
7   c   103      0   False
```

Thank you in advance for your advice

Comment: There is always 103 and 104 for each class?

Comment: In some cases we have two rows of the same code with same class but different qty. Which quantity should be used in those cases?

Comment: no there are different codes like 105 or 106

Comment: one class is equal to one order, code 103 is the item request and code 104 is the item receipt so i will take the sum. good question thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
regle2 = lambda x: x.loc[x['code'].eq('103'), 'qty'].max() \
                   > x.loc[x['code'].eq('104'), 'qty'].min()

df['bool'] = df['class'].map(df.groupby('class').apply(regle2))
print(df)

# Output:
  class code  qty   bool
0     a  103    4  False
1     a  104    4  False
2     b  103    5  False
3     b  103    6  False
4     b  104   11  False
5     c  104    8  False
6     c  104    9  False
7     c  103    0  False
```

Note: you don't need to check if the class 103 or 104 exists because when you use `max` or `min` on an empty dataframe, the return value is `nan`.